# In kryonet, how do I disconnect from a server without stopping my program?

Tags: java, tcp, network-programming, disconnect, kryonet

I am trying to make a simple `TCP` chat program, and I want the user to be able to start the program, then be able to enter a specific `ip` to connect to, and then disconnect from that specific server, and then connect to another after that.

I know that the client is connected once it runs `client.connect(timeout, ip, port)`, but the only way I know of to disconnect the client from the server is by exiting the program.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Would you please mind adding some more proper Java code so that your question is answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `client.stop();` to disconnect